# Maximum Subarray detection in Java using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to implement the **maximum sub array problem** in Java using recursion.

But my code keeps throwing exception.  I am unable to figure out what is causing the problem, I believe that this might be occurring because the base case of recursion is bottoming out  at the very first iteration.

Thanks

```
 import java.lang.*;

    class Subarray{
        int low;
        int high;
        int sum;


        Subarray MaxCrossSub(int a[], int low, int mid, int high)
        {
            Subarray sub=new Subarray();

            double leftsum=Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            double rightsum=Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
            double sum=0;
            int maxleft=0;
            int maxright=0;
            for(int i=mid;i>=low;i--)
            {
                sum=sum+a[i];
                if(sum>leftsum)
                {
                    leftsum=sum;
                    maxleft=i;
                }

            }

            sum=0;
            for(int i=mid+1;i>=high;i++)
            {
                sum=sum+a[i];
                if(sum>rightsum)
                    rightsum=sum;
                    maxright=i;

            }


            sub.low=maxleft;
            sub.high=maxright;
            sub.sum=maxleft+maxright;
            return sub;
        }
        Subarray MaxSub(int a[],int low,int high) throws Exception
        {
            Subarray leftsub=new Subarray();
            Subarray rightsub=new Subarray();
            Subarray crosssub=new Subarray();

            if(low==high)
            {
                leftsub.low=low;
                leftsub.high=low;
                leftsub.sum=a[low];
            }
            int mid=(low+high)/2;
            leftsub=MaxSub(a,low,mid);
            rightsub=MaxSub(a,mid+1,high);
            crosssub=MaxCrossSub(a,low,mid,high);


            if(leftsub.sum>rightsub.sum && leftsub.sum>crosssub.sum)
                return leftsub;
            else if(rightsub.sum>leftsub.sum && rightsub.sum>crosssub.sum)
            return rightsub;
            else
                return crosssub;



        }
    }
    public class MaximumSubarray {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Subarray sub=new Subarray();
        int a[]={13,-3,-25,20,-3,-16,-23,18,20,-7,12,-5,-22,15-4,7};
        int low=0;
        int high=16;


        sub=sub.MaxSub(a,low,high);

        System.out.println("low"+sub.low);
        System.out.println("high"+sub.high);
        System.out.println("Sum"+sub.sum);






    }
    }
```

Comment: can you add few sample of Maximum Subarray?

Comment: Saying **my code keeps throwing exception**  is not enough. You need to provide exception details too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that "throws Exeption" in your MaxSub method is necessary?

Comment: This has to be a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is a non-ending recursion caused by

```
        int mid=(low+high)/2;
        leftsub=MaxSub(a,low,mid);
```

I can't understand the idea you are willing to implement this algorithm when O(n) algorithm is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem).

It's Java version will look like this:

```
    static int max_subarray( int[] a ){
        int max_ending_here = 0, max_so_far = 0;

        for( int x : a ){
            max_ending_here = Math.max( 0, max_ending_here + x );
            max_so_far = Math.max( max_so_far, max_ending_here );
        }
        return max_so_far;
    }
```